# [Django]: How can i read next entry from MySql upon clicking a button from HTML form

Tags: html, django

I am new to Django as well as HTML, I have 5 entries in database (MySql) `x.objects.all` returns all in one go but as per requirement i want to read each row upon clicking of a button from HTML form. Tried `x.object.get(pk=var)` by changing var on each click but somehow not able to do it.

views.py

```
----------
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from .models import emp

def index(request):
    album=emp.objects.all()
    context={'album': album}
    return render(request,'Home/index.html',context)

index.html
----------
<form action = "{% url 'Home:index' %}" method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
<ol>
    <li> {{ album.Name}}</li>
    <input type="radio" name="Option" value=1 > {{album.Option_1}}<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Option" value=1 > {{album.Option_2}}<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Option" value=1 > {{album.Option_3}}<br>
</ol>
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Next" />
</form>
```

Any pointer will be helpful here, thanks in advance.

Madhur

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Thanks for reply, have added the code.

Comment: Commenting after long break, i used AJAX to get next item from DB without refreshing page.